# R: Select Rows from Data Frame based on condition

Tags: r

I have the following data frames

**User_Details:**

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
|   Name      |  Address  |   Phone   |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
| John Doe    | Somewhere | 123456789 |
| Jane Doe    | Somewhere | 234567891 |
| Jack Russel | Somewhere | 234567891 |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**User_Transaction_Count:**

```html
+-------------+-----------+
|   Name      | Frequency |
+-------------+-----------+
| John Doe    | 2         |
| Jane Doe    | 5         |
| Jack Russel | 2         |
+-------------+-----------+
```

What I want to do is get the details of the user with the most transactions.
So in the above case, Jane Doe has the most transactions, so I need to fetch her details into a data frame.

I tried the following code:

```
User_details[which(user_details$Name = User_Transaction_Count[(which.max(User_Transaction_Count$Frequency)),]$Name)]
```

But I get this error:

`Error: unexpected '=' in "ad_maxState <- accidental_deaths[which(accidental_deaths$State ="`

Comment: The `=` is assigning.  You need comparison `==`

Comment: You could also use `merge(subset(User_Transaction_Count, Frequency == max(Frequency), Name), User_Details)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to T. Ciffréo answer and found the solution:

```
User_details[User_details$Name==as.character(User_transaction_Count[which.max(User_transaction_Count$Frequency),]$Name),]
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the user with the maximum Frequency, we can use:

```
with(User_Transaction_Count,Name[[which.max(Frequency)]])
```

However, if the `User` column is using the `factor()` datatype (which is usually the default), we need to convert it to a string to be used for lookup. Otherwise internal value for "John Doe" in one `data.frame` may not be the same as "John Doe" in the other.

```
maxUser <- as.character(with(User_Transaction_Count,Name[[which.max(Frequency)]]))
```

Then we can perform the lookup in the other `data.frame`.

```
result <- User_Details[User_Details$Name == maxUser,]
```

This may take a long time if the table is very large, so it may be best to create an index for this

```
#build index
library(hash)
userIdx <- hash(as.character(User_Details$Name),1:nrow(User_Details))

#use index
maxUser <- as.character(with(User_Transaction_Count,Name[[which.max(Frequency)]]))
result <- User_Details[userIdx[[maxUser]],]
```

Output:

```
> result
      Name   Address     Phone
2 Jane Doe Somewhere 234567891
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code:**

```
User_details[User_details$Name==User_transaction_Count[max(User_transaction_Count$Frequency),]$Name,]$Name
```

Comment: I get the following error for your code:   Error in Ops.factor(accidental_deaths$State, State_Count[which.max(State_Count$Freq),  : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: Maybe did i forget an unique() as this: User_details[User_details$Name==unique(User_transaction_Count[max(User_transaction_Count$Frequency),]$Name),]$Name